# Found important issue with SQL Server 2008 R2. Need Advice

Tags: sql-server, installation

Recently while installing my copy of SQL Server 2008 R2; the power went OFF. So now it does say the some features are installed and some are not but when I run SQL server detection manager it says that there is nothing. I inquired further and there is probably some problem in the registry counter. I also tried uninstalling SQL server's installed components from Control Panel and I was successful in uninstalling SOME components but some others are now saying that some totally other components are now missing and HENCE it cannot be uninstalled

The log error is below:

> Warning 26003. Microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2 Setup Support Files cannot
>   be uninstalled because the following products are installed:
>   * SQL Server 2008 R2 Common Files
>   * SQL Server 2008 R2 Database Engine Shared.

Please can I have some expert or novice (practically anyone) advice and solution for this issue.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In most cases where you hit this issue you will just need to follow the manual uninstall steps Microsoft provides [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms143412.aspx). That will, in cases I have had to, get the system to a point where you can successful reinstall SQL Server to a working state.